# How to write a message recovered from an MS Exchange server via JavaMail as an EML without parsing

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am not a programmer. I am a software solution designer. For compliance reasons I have to recover the messages received in our MS Exchange mailboxes and save them in their original form  as an EML file, before I can save them to our CRM database for treatment by backoffice personnel.

My question is : Can I read the message and write the inputstream directly to the EML file without parsing it?

Our Sofware Architect and Judicial teams want to be sure that the contents are exactly equal to the original received e-mails in case of regulatory audit/investigation.

Also, can I save it to a blob-type database field and create a link that can be used to download the file?

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I am original a COBOL analyst.

Thanks!

Our CRM software package uses JavaMail to send and receive e-mail messages from our MS Exchange Server, and stores them in the package database (Oracle Exadata) for issue/ticket management.

Answer (score 0):

EML files are MIME format.  You can use JavaMail to read the MIME content of a message and write it to an EML file without parsing it first.

However, note that Exchange does not store the message in MIME format.  So, even though the message may be received in MIME format, Exchange may transform it into its own internal format, and then transform it back to MIME when the message is read.  Depending on your Exchange configuration, this transformation may or may not preserve the original MIME content exactly.  In some case Exchange will transform the message into a different MIME format that it thinks will be easier for the client to process.  I'm not an Exchange expert so if this concerns you you'll need to look into the Exchange documentation in more detail.

Comment: I will take your observations to our Eschange Support Team and research some Exchange resources myself. Thanks a lot Bill!